# Retrasar envio de SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

Quisiera saber cómo hago para retrasar 20 segundos en envío del siguiente SMS. Quiero que se envíen varios con una diferencia de 20 segundos cada uno.

Éste es mi código:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Handler;


public class Mensajes extends Activity {

    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    EditText txttime;
    Button btnSend;
    String p = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes);

        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nrotelf);
        txtMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txttime = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnsms);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     // Obtener numero de telefono y mensaje
                checkSMSStatePermission();
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = "Mensaje de prueba";

                // If phone number & message is not empty
                if (phoneNo.length()>0){
                    sendMessage(phoneNo, message);
                    // If phone number or message not empty
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Por favor ingrese el numero de telefono del GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Function send message sms
    private void sendMessage(String phoneNo, String message){
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS enviado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Fallido. Intente de nuevo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cambiando un poco tu función de sendMessage esto te serviría:

```
private void sendMessage(final String phoneNo, final String message) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //enviar sms luego de 20s
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            PendingIntent sentPI;
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            //el primer parametro recibe el contexto asi que lo 
            // llamas desde un fragment tendras
            //cambiar el this por getContext()
            sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, null);
        }
    }, 20000);
}
```

esto funciono para mi para enviar msjs de texto y el postDelayed te pide el tiempo antes de ejecutarse en milisegundos.

espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Donde colocaria el codigo? tenviendo en cuenta que necesito enviar varios SMS. Con una diferencia de 20 segundos entre si? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: reemplaza tu función de sendMessage por esta y listo... cada vez que presionen el btnSend se crea un msj que se envía en 20 segundos.. que es lo que entendí que necesitas. ahora necesitas que los msjs se envíen con 20 segundos de diferencia entre si?

Comment: Si necesito enviar 10 sms y que se envien con una diferencia de 20 segundos c/u

Comment: pero como cargar los msj? seria del mismo msj? si son el mismo msj puedes usar una variable en la clase Mensajes  que sirva de contador y si son msjs diferentes puedes usar un arraylist que actué de pila.

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono bien, lo de los mensajes programados aun no lo tengo claro, de igual forma muchas gracias.