# Delay varios SMS Android Studio

Tags: sms

Estimada comunidad. como podria hacer para que a la hora de enviar varios SMS haya una diferencia de X segundos en el envio. Donde X es un tiempo de espera distinto para cada mensaje.
Por ejemplo :

- Mensaje 1 : Inmediatamente al pulsar el botón
- Mensaje 2 : 20 segundos después del mensaje 1
- Mensaje 3 : 10 segundos después del mensaje 2
- Mensaje 4 : 5 segundos después del mensaje 3
- Mensaje >=5 : 3 segundos después del mensaje anterior.

  Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

Aqui el codigo.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public class otrosSMS extends Activity {



    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    EditText txttime;
    Button btnSend;
    String p = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;

    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes);






        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nrotelf);
        txtMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txttime = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnsms);



        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                // Obtener numero de telefono y mensaje

                checkSMSStatePermission();
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = "Mensaje de prueba";
                String message1 = "Mensaje de prueba 2";
                String message2= "Mensaje de prueba 3";


                // Si el numero y el sms no esta vacio
                if (phoneNo.length()>0){
                    sendMessage(phoneNo, message);
                    sendMessage(phoneNo, message1);
                    sendMessage(phoneNo, message2);

                    // If phone number or message not empty
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Por favor ingrese el numero de telefono del GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    // Funcion Enviar mensaje SMS
    private void sendMessage(final String phoneNo, final String message) {
        try {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //enviar sms luego de 20s
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    PendingIntent sentPI;
                    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                    //el primer parametro recibe el contexto asi que lo
                    // llamas desde un fragment tendras
                    //cambiar el this por getContext()
                    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(otrosSMS.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, null);
                }
            }, 20000);
            





            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS enviado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Fallido. Intente de nuevo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: mismo usuario, misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83683/retrasar-envio-de-sms
no es que no quieran hacerte caso amigo, es que aveces no hay quien pueda responder a tu pregunta, ¿ya investigaste cómo podrías hacerlo? ¿o sólo estás preguntando para no tener que buscar?
por lo mientras votaré por duplicada la pregunta.

Comment: No es la misma pregunta, en la primera pregunto como retrasar el envio de un sms, en esta pregunto como retrasar el envio de varios SMS diferentes.

Comment: y cual es la diferencia entre retrasar uno o varios?? no estas retrasando uno varias veces?

Comment: Por ejemplo necesito que se envie "mensaje de prueba", a los 20 segundos  "mensaje de prueba 2" a los 30 segundos "mensaje de prueba 3" para que no salgan todos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para añadir esa información que has puesto en comentarios. Si no es eso lo que querías decir no dudes en revertirla, Delvis Barrios.

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener idea de este lenguaje, pero viendo que ya te contestaron lo que necesitabas, solo que no lo supiste interpretar.

A la función sendmessage tendrias que agregarle el parámetro del tiempo que quieres que espere.
A la función postDelayed, en lugar de pasarle 20000 por defecto, deberías pasarle ese tiempo que recibiste como parámetro..
Y cada llamada a sendmessage, debería decir el tiempo de espera.

Ojo que si todo esto es asincronico, en realidad el tiempo de delay del segundo es el tiempo de delay del primero mas el tiempo de delay del segundo...